# Find continuous records with equal values characters

Tags: partitioning

I need your kind support to resolve this issue.

I have a table contains similar to the below data :

```
|AccountNo|remarks    |
|Q32571   |Actual Read|
|Q32571   |Locked     |
|Q32571   |Actual Read|
|Q32571   |Actual Read|
|Q32571   |Actual Read|
|Q32571   |Locked     |
|Q32571   |Actual Read|
```

The expected result shall give me the continuous records only with the same remarks

```
|AccountNo|TotCont|
|Q32571   |    3  |
```

Can anyone help please

thanks

Comment: Without a column to `ORDER BY`, your answer will be random.

Comment: Is this a subset of a result? Can you show us more data?

Comment: i cannot use the order by here because it will show wrong information. this data is ordered by date.

Comment: the top portion is not subset of the result it is the table data. the second portion is the result

Comment: this is a similar question but with integers. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/129999/find-continuous-records-with-equal-values?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa <br/> i have tried with this one and it gave me error related to the conversion

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to have a way to determine the order of rows, so I added an `ID` column to my example.  I also added another `AccountNumber` and mixed the data up a bit to verify that my solution would work for other accounts.  You did not specify your RDBMS.  My solution uses SQL Server.

```
--Set up demo data
DECLARE @T TABLE
    ([ID] int,[AccountNumber] varchar(10), [Remarks] varchar(100))
;

insert into @t(ID,AccountNumber,Remarks) values
(1,'Q32571','Actual Read'),
(2,'Q32571','Locked'),
(3,'Q11111','Locked'),
(4,'Q11111','Locked'),
(5,'Q32571','Actual Read'),
(6,'Q32571','Actual Read'),
(7,'Q32571','Actual Read'),
(8,'Q32571','Locked'),
(9,'Q32571','Actual Read'),
(10,'Q11111','Actual Read'),
(11,'Q11111','Locked')
;

--The actual query 
;with _groupings as
(
select AccountNumber, Remarks, count(*) as CountConsecutive
from (select t.*,
             (row_number() over (order by AccountNumber, ID) -
              row_number() over (partition by Remarks order by AccountNumber,ID)
             ) as grp
      from @t t
     ) t
group by AccountNumber, grp, Remarks
)
select AccountNumber, Max(CountConsecutive) as CountConsecutive
from _groupings 
group by AccountNumber
```

---

```
| AccountNumber | CountConsecutive |
|---------------|------------------|
| Q11111        | 2                |
| Q32571        | 3                |
```

Comment: thank you very much. that is really helps and solve the issue